# change the image of the dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, jquery

pressing a button a new row with a textbox, a button, and an image is created

```
$("#dynamic_table").append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="url_textbox"></td><td><input type="button" id="load_image_btn" value="Load Image"></td><td><img id="image_id"></td></tr>');
```

what i would like to achieve is when i press the load_image_btn the image src of the corresponding row be loaded with the url i insert in the url_textbox

```
 $(document).on("click", "#load_image_btn", function(){

//http://mith.umd.edu/engl668k/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/twitter-logo-small.jpg
//http://demo-old-ofbiz.apache.org/images/products/GZ-1000/small.png
//alert(this.id);
var url = $("#url_textbox").val();
  if (url != ""){
      $("#image_id").attr("src", url);
  }

});
```

using the above piece of code and while i press the button of the first created row the image is loaded as it is expected in the first row. The problem is that when i append a new row to the dynamically created table and while i press for example the load_image_btn in the second row of in any row except the first one the img src remains blank.

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: how can i change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique in your code, so you need to use `class` instead of `id`. In your case it will only select the first element which have that `id`

```js
$("#dynamic_table").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="url_textbox"></td><td><input type="button" class="load_image_btn" value="Load Image"></td><td><img class="image_id"></td></tr>').append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="url_textbox"></td><td><input type="button" class="load_image_btn" value="Load Image"></td><td><img class="image_id"></td></tr>').append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="url_textbox"></td><td><input type="button" class="load_image_btn" value="Load Image"></td><td><img class="image_id"></td></tr>');


$(document).on("click", ".load_image_btn", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('tr'),
  // getting parent tr    
    url = $(".url_textbox", parent).val();
    // getting value of textbox inside the same tr
  if (url != "") {
    $(".image_id", parent).attr("src", url);
    // getting image tag inside the same tr
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dynamic_table"></table>
```

Comment: the "parent" variable simply gets the id of the row where the load_image_btn that was clicked belongs?

Comment: @tsiro : parents variable caching the parent `tr` which contains the button, based on that parent context we are selecting the other elements

Comment: ok so when i press the button of the second row parent variable contains the second row...am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the `id`,

use `class` instead. like `<input type="text" class="url_textbox">`

```
$(document).on("click", ".load_image_btn", function(){
  var url = $(".url_textbox",$(this).closest('tr')).val();
  if (url != ""){
      $(".image_id",$(this).closest('tr')).attr("src", url);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dynamic_table").append('
   <tr>
       <td><input type="text" class="url_textbox"></td>
       <td><input type="button" class="load_image_btn" value="Load Image"></td>
       <td><img class="image_id"></td>
   </tr>
 ');
  $(document).on("click", ".load_image_btn", function(){

        var loadImage = new Image();
        var loadImg =  loadImage.src = url = $(".url_textbox", parent).val();;
        if (loadImg != "")
        {
           $('.image_id", parent').attr('src', loadImg ); 
        }
   });
```